# please i need fix i just added a Gif and its crushing when starting here i sthe log cat

Tags: android, android-studio

2022-07-30 11:08:44.355 21395-21395/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.tekiquiz, PID: 21395 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tekiquiz/com.example.tekiquiz.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView at com.example.tekiquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method`enter code here`)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)  2022-07-30 11:08:44.381 21395-21395/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21395 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

it seems pretty obvious :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView at com.example.tekiquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
```

in your [MainActivity.java] line 31 , you are trying to cast [**GifImageView Object**] to [**TextView Object**]

1. You cannot do that !!
2. You can cast objects when they are inherited one-by-another ( e.g Button can be cast to TextView because Buttons are inherited from TextViews )
3. GifImageView is not inherited from TextView !!!